# javascript Get value instead of promise

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

I would like get a value from a promise but dont know how.

I tried this way:

```
function connected(p) {

var url = getURL();

async function getURL() {
    var test = "";
    let tab = await browser.tabs.query({currentWindow: true, active: true});
    tab.then(function(tabb){
        test = tabb[0].url.toString()
    });
    return test;
}

async function getURL() {
    var tab = await browser.tabs.query({currentWindow: true, active: true});
    return tab[0].url;
}

    console.log(url.toString()); // Promise
}
```

The first function get rejected the second one is fullfilled.

Comment: Maybe change `var url = getURL()` to `var url = await getURL()`

Comment: Also if you use `await` you don't need `then()`. If you await you will get the result directly

Comment: I suggest to spend 20 minutes and read about Promises. It will clarify a lot and you will be able to fix your code yourself. For example start here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like get a value from a promise but dont know how.

The only way to get a value from a promise is by using `.then()` on the promise or within the same function, you can use `await`.

An `async` function always returns a promise.  Within a function, you can use `await` to "wait" for a promise to get the value, but that is not the case for the return value for the function.  The function always returns a promise and you always use either `await` or `.then()` to get the value from a promise.

So, your second `getURL()` function returns a promise who's resolved value is the url you want.  To get that value, you use `.then()` on the returned promise:

```
async function getURL() {
    var tab = await browser.tabs.query({currentWindow: true, active: true});
    return tab[0].url;
}

getURL().then(url => {
    console.log(url);
});
```

Or, there's really no big advantage in using `await` here so you could also just do:

```
function getURL() {
    return browser.tabs.query({currentWindow: true, active: true}).then(tab => {
        return tab[0].url;
    });

}

getURL().then(url => {
    console.log(url);
});
```

---

Your first version of `getURL()` does not work because your function returns BEFORE your `.then()` handler is called and thus you always just return `""`.

Comment: I tried your code like this: var url = getURL().then(function(resp) {url = resp}); But "url" is still a promise

Comment: @R.Kut - Yeah.  `getURL().then()` returns a promise.  You can't get the data outside of the `.then()` handler.  That's how async operations work.  You must use the result inside the `.then()` handler.

Answer (score 1):

`async` function returns `promise` so you can only get `promise` as a result.
so do

```
var url = getUrl()
url.then((resp) => {console.log(resp)});
```

Answer (score 1):

`async` and `await` - these resolve promises and give you value directly.
Remove await and `.then` works.